# How to mirror/reflect a vector relative to the last value

Tags: r, vector, reflection, mirror

how can I reflect the vector relative to the last value, I don't know how to explain it in words, so I will show it with pictures
[image]

[image]

I tried to do it myself, but my code only works with linear vector

```
x <- 1:10 # some linear vector
y <- rev(cumsum(c(tail(x,1),diff(x))))

plot(rep(NA,20),t="l" , ylim = c(1,20))
lines(x,col=2,lwd=5)
lines(y,col=4,lty=5)
```

[image]

If i take an arbitrary vector, my code doesn't work

```
set.seed(123)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(10))  # real vector
y <- rev(cumsum(c(tail(x,1),diff(x))))

plot(rep(NA,20),t="l" , ylim = c(-5,10))
lines(x,col=2,lwd=5)
lines(y,col=4,lty=5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are after is

```
set.seed(123)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(10))

y <- x-2*(x-tail(x,1))

plot(rep(NA,20),t="l" , ylim = c(-5,10))
lines(x,col=2,lwd=5)
lines(y,col=4,lty=5)
```

The `x-2*(x-tail(x,1))` part adjusts each point with respect to the last point in the line. Basically you find the distance and substract double the distance to move the "opposite side" of that last point. You can move the terms around to simplify a bit to

```
y <- 2*tail(x,1)-x
```

[image]